# How to pull Project info from Excel into MS Project, using a MS Project macro

Tags: vba, ms-project

I'm working within MS Project and trying to use a macro to import project information from a spreadsheet to MS Project. What I have so far works fine for importing the Task information from the spreadsheet. I'd also like to import the Enterprise Custom Fields Project information, like Project Departments -- the information you would see in the Project Information dialog box. I *am* able to pass hard-coded information to those fields using `ProjectSummaryTask.SetField`, like this:

```
ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.SetField FieldID:=FieldNameToFieldConstant("Project Departments", pjProject), Value:="Analytics"
```

But I don't know how to access the actual Excel spreadsheet and reference its cells that contain the information I need, so that I could then use a variable with that information in place of the text ("Analytics") in the example above.

The entirety of what I have so far is:

```
Sub Import()

MapEdit Name:="Map ", Create:=True, OverwriteExisting:=True, DataCategory:=0, CategoryEnabled:=True, _
    TableName:="Cleaned", FieldName:="Name", ExternalFieldName:="Summary", ExportFilter:="All Tasks", ImportMethod:=0, _
    HeaderRow:=True, AssignmentData:=False, TextDelimiter:=Chr$(9), TextFileOrigin:=0, UseHtmlTemplate:=False, IncludeImage:=False
MapEdit Name:="Map ", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="Outline Level", ExternalFieldName:="Outline_Level"
MapEdit Name:="Map ", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="Created", ExternalFieldName:="Created"
MapEdit Name:="Map ", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="Start", ExternalFieldName:="Start_date"
MapEdit Name:="Map ", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="Finish", ExternalFieldName:="Finish"
MapEdit Name:="Map ", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="% Complete", ExternalFieldName:="%_Complete"
MapEdit Name:="Map ", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="Notes", ExternalFieldName:="Notes_w_Comments"
FileOpenEx Name:="Mypath\Project Import Prep.xlsx", _
    ReadOnly:=False, Merge:=0, FormatID:="MSProject.ACE.14", map:="Map ", DoNotLoadFromEnterprise:=True
    
ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.SetField FieldID:=FieldNameToFieldConstant("Project Departments", pjProject), Value:="Analytics"
ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.SetField FieldID:=FieldNameToFieldConstant("Customer", pjProject), Value:="OA"

End Sub
```

Everything works, but I want to automatically populate the Project Departments and Customer fields from my spreadsheet, using variables instead of the hard code.

What do I need to do to enable and use the spreadsheet content as variables? Can you at least point me in the right direction?

I've done a lot of digging for answers, but everything I've found so far has been for working from within Excel instead of MS Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code that you can run from within Project to automate Excel and get the values from a worksheet:

```
Sub GetValuesFromExcel()

    Dim xl As Excel.Application
    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xl.Visible = True
    
    Dim wbk As Excel.Workbook
    Set wbk = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\...\<filename>.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
    
    Dim Dept As String
    Dim Customer As String
    Dept = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
    Customer = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")
    
    wbk.Close False
    xl.Quit
    
    ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.SetField FieldNameToFieldConstant("Project Departments"), Dept
    ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.SetField FieldNameToFieldConstant("Customer"), Customer
    
End Sub
```

This code uses early binding to the Excel object library so you'll need to set a reference to that file (Tools Menu: References, check the box for the Microsoft Excel Object Library).

And of course update the filename, sheet name, and range references.

Comment: Thank you so much @Rachel. This is exactly what I needed to get me up and running.